# Using jsvc on aix 64-Bit

Tags: 64-bit, apache-commons, aix, jsvc

After modifying the configure script to add support for AIX6 and changing `CFLGAS` to add CPU type as `PPC64` & adding `-maix64` flags I am able to compile `apache-commons on AIX6 machine in 64-Bit mode` using gcc and `IBM JDK 7`.

But, i am unable to run jsvc to start any service or tomcat as service. I tried to set `LIBPATH` to include all `JVM library locations` and did not see any progress.

Below is the error i observed when running jsvc in debug mode.

> Attempting to locate VM configuration file
>   /usr/java71_64/jre/lib/ppc64/jvm.cfg
>
> Found VM configuration file at /usr/java71_64/jre/lib/ppc64/jvm.cfg
>
> Found VM j9vm definition in configuration
>
> Cannot locate library for VM j9vm (skipping)
>
> Found VM hotspot definition in configuration
>
> Cannot locate library for VM hotspot (skipping)
>
> Found VM classic definition in configuration
>
> Cannot locate library for VM classic (skipping)
>
> Found VM native definition in configuration
>
> Cannot locate library for VM native (skipping)
>
> Found VM green definition in configuration
>
> Cannot locate library for VM green (skipping)
>
> Java Home located in /usr/java71_64
>
> +-- DUMPING JAVA HOME STRUCTURE ------------------------
>
> | Java Home:       "/usr/java71_64"
>
> | Java VM Config.: "/usr/java71_64/jre/lib/ppc64/jvm.cfg"
>
> | Found JVMs:      0
>
> +-------------------------------------------------------

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by changing the commons-daemon source code. File "location.c" holds search path of JVM library for all operating systems. I added case for AIX in code with JVM library paths and recompiled code. This solved my problem.